# Draco compression, gzip and deploying to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, three.js, vite, vercel

I have a Three.js app. Inside, I use Vite for bundling and Vercel for deployment. Inside of my app, I have .glb model. This is already a Draco compressed version of a model with a size of 513kb. When I deploy the app to Vercel, the size is smaller. Why?
Other files are pretty much the same size as I have them, but .glb model almost halved.
Everything is working fine, but I would like to understand.

[image]

Comment: I think Vercel have a limited file types that are gzipped. You can see more info here: https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/compression